# how to format a button on each side of an H3 tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

plan

```
[button] [h3] [button]
```

html

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
<h3>Title may or may not be long enough to break to new line</h3>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
```

Should be simple right? I keep ending up with either

```
[button] [h3]
[button]
```

or

```
[button]
[h3]
[button]
```

Comment: use table html table.. it'll help you

Comment: h3 is a block level element and will occupy an entire line unless you change it's display to inline or inline-block.. i suggest inline-block.

Comment: yes I understand that, but even with inline-block it will take the last [button] to the next line with the line break (if the title is long enough to cause a line break)

Comment: @KeithA, can you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s9x2kxyz/

There are more ways to do it, but the above fiddle shows one way that's fairly simple:

HTML:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
<h3>Title may or may not be long enough to break to new line</h3>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
```

CSS:

```
h3, span {display:block;float:left;text-align:center;}
h3 {width:80%;margin-top:10px;}
span {width:10%;margin-top:15px;}
```

The vertical alignment is the part that can get tricky when you don't know how many lines there may be on the h3, but that's the nature of the beast in this case...the `margin-top` in my example is just showing how you can control it a bit...it will likely need to vary based on the size of the font, etc. Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

EDIT: Just wanted to note, I've used the original HTML for the purpose of answering the question, but depending on what they are being used for, the  elements here should probably be contained in an `<a>` (or `<button>`)element to be a bit more semantic, and the CSS in the solution would then be on the `<a>` instead of the span.  The main benefit from this would be to help normalize the behavior across browsers and devices if something is happening when clicking/hovering/focusing those elements.

Answer (score 2):

How about this without writing any additional CSS you can simply use "col-xs" of bootstrap to keep the buttons on same level,

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/znot1r11/4/)

You can add col-xs class to you buttons and h3 as,

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left col-xs-2">icon</span>
<h3 class="col-xs-8">Title may or may not be long enough to break to new line</h3>
<span class="col-xs-2 glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">icon</span>
```

Comment: yeah, this was my current work around. It's close, but it bothers me that it needs all that extra padding

Comment: this would be what you're after if you want the text to break while keeping the buttons on the same level. just add text-align: center on the span and h3 and you're golden.

Comment: @godmode I'm not sure keeping both the buttons and the title at same level without the title getting break is possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use padding-left and padding right to create a space for your left and right buttons on both sides. Then position the buttons using absolute position. This snippet is useful if you have fixed width buttons and dynamic width content.

```css
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
#h3-container {
    position: relative; 
    padding-left: 100px; 
    padding-right: 100px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
}

button.left {
    left: 0;
}

button.right {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="h3-container">
    <button class="left">Button</button>
    <h3>Title may or may not be long enough to break to new line</h3>
    <button class="right">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this:

```
div{
    position: relative;
}

h3{
    padding: 0 30px;
}

span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

span:last-child{
    right: 0;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/znot1r11/3/

Comment: yeah until the title is long enough to break to a new line

Comment: @godmode in that case, wrap them in another div.

Comment: @godmode but if the h3(title) is long enough it will definetly be break to new line, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: it's okay if the title breaks to a new line, but I want that 2nd [button] to stay on the same "level" as the first

Answer (score 0):

here's a another solution that will do the trick.

```css
span{
   width:20%;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
}
h3{
   width:60%;
   float:left;    
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">icon</span>
<h3>Title may or may not be long enough to break to new line</h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">icon</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place the span inside the block-level H3 element like this:

```
<h1><span class="small glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span> Let's play? <span class="small glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></h1>
```